# In what cases will a websocket close event tell you wasClean is false?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

In what cases will a websocket close event tell you wasClean is false? For example:

```
connection.onclose = function(event) {
   if(!event.wasClean) {
      // whyyyyyyy???
   }
}
```

Comment: Probably specific codes from this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

Comment: In my case, I'm getting code 1006. Are you suggesting that wasClean is set to true for certain code numbers? If that's the case, I don't even see a point to looking at the value of wasClean over using the codes.

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I think the `wasClean` is a more generic way of telling if the connection was closed cleanly, and then you're able to get "more information" by looking at the code. But yes, it seems that `wasClean` and the status code are related

Answer (score 12):

wasClean property is set to false when the WebSocket connection did not close via the close handshake.
i.e. by not receiving a valid Close frame from the server.

And from documentation: *"CloseEvent.wasClean Returns a Boolean that Indicates whether or not the connection was cleanly closed*"

Comment: I think this is supposed to be true? I can get "wasClean == true" if I let the client initiate the close() and the server finish with a close() (which is spec). I get a "true" on chrome but not on firefox if the server initiates the close(), but in all cases, I get the code I wanted (1000) and the message I wanted /shrug.

Comment: @AndrewPikul I observe the same difference between Chrome and Firefox

Comment: The behavior may have changed at this point, they do update quite frequently. Maybe a maintainer saw my comment X'D